# Assign a value based on the first letter of each word in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a column 2 (i.e., firstletter) with a numeric value (e.g., 1) assigned depending on the first letter of a word in column 1 (i.e., catname). In the sample dataset, column 1 has a list of cats' names and I want to assign 1 to cats whose first letter of the name starts with A, 2 to cats whose first letter of the name starts with B, 3 to C, and so forth until the letter Z.

```
df <- data.frame(catname=c("Ave", "Ares", "Aze", "Bill", "Buz", "Chris", "Chase", "Charlie", "Coco"))
```

At the moment, I can only think of doing this using case_when() function, e.g.,

```
df %>% mutate(firstletter = case_when(str_start(catname) == "A" ~ "1",
                                      str_start(catname) == "B" ~ "2",
                                      str_start(catname) == "C" ~ "3"))
```

So the resulting outcome I hope is

```
| catname  | firstletter    |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Ave      | 1              |
| Ares     | 1              |
| Aze      | 1              |
| Bill     | 2              |
| Buz      | 2              |
| Chris    | 3              |
| Chase    | 3              |
| Charlie  | 3              |
| Coco     | 3              |
```

I would appreciate your insights if there is another way to approach my problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry--I added my question. I am asking if there is a different way to create a column 2 than what I am thinking of using case_when().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset to the first character, and then match against the build in LETTER array if you want the values to always be 1...26 even if some letters might be missing

```
df %>% mutate(first=match(substr(catname,1,1), LETTERS))
```

If you only want numbers for observed values, you can use the factor trick:

```
df %>% mutate(first=as.numeric(factor(substr(catname,1,1))))
```

Comment: thank you!!! I did not realize how as.numeric(factor) can be used this way.

Answer (score 3):

Please also check the below code with `data.table::rleid()`

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) # str_sub

data.frame(catname=c("Ave", "Ares", "Aze", "Bill", "Buz", "Chris", "Chase", "Charlie", "Coco")) %>% 
  mutate(firstletter=rleid(str_sub(catname,1,1)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  catname firstletter
1     Ave           1
2    Ares           1
3     Aze           1
4    Bill           2
5     Buz           2
6   Chris           3
7   Chase           3
8 Charlie           3
9    Coco           3
```

Comment: Good idea with `rleid` +1. Please add `library(data.table)
library(stringr)` to your code.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the new `consecutive_id`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0
df %>% 
  mutate(firstletter = consecutive_id(substr(catname, 1, 1)))
```

Also new, the `case_match` option which avoids repetition and allows more flexibility:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(firstletter = case_match(substr(catname, 1, 1),
                                  "A" ~ 1,
                                  "B" ~ 2,
                                  "C" ~ 3))
```

Comment: Never used before. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

Here we use `which` to determine the position of the first letter:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(firstletter = which(LETTERS == substr(catname,1,1)))
```

```
 catname firstletter
  <chr>         <int>
1 Ave               1
2 Ares              1
3 Aze               1
4 Bill              2
5 Buz               2
6 Chris             3
7 Chase             3
8 Charlie           3
9 Coco              3
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your new codes in a named vector and use match

```
> match(substr(df$catname,1,1),c("1"="A","2"="B","3"="C"))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
```